# Wpf Databinding MenuItem with XPath

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xpath

My application uses a Menu with some MenuItems. Because of localization I would like to bind the Header property of the MenuItem to a node value in a xml file.

Here are the relevant parts of my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider Source="Labels.xml" x:Key="langProvider" XPath="Labels"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource langProvider}, XPath=Label[@Name\=\'File\']}"/>
```

and here is my Labels.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Labels>
    <Label Name="File">_Datei</Label>
</Labels>
```

It works, except when I start the application, the MenuItem shows "_Datei" instead of "Datei" - therefore I cannot access this menuItem by pressing Alt+D. Is it impossible to bind the Header property to an xml value with XPath and still keep the hotkey function WPF provides?

Comment: Just a thought, but shouldn't your XPath be `Labels/Label ...` not just `Label ...`?

Comment: It works both ways, I guess the child element appends its XPath expression to the expression of the parent.